# Inequality over infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

I have been dealing with this inequality:

For some positive real numbers $x_1,...,x_n$ such that $\prod^n_{j=1}x_j>1$ Prove that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sum^{n}_{j=1}x_j^{k+1}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}{x^{2k+1}_j}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\prod^n_{j=1}{x_j}}-1}$$

Since there is a infinite sum, I though about trying some kind of induction over the sum first sum ($\sum^{m}_{k=1}$) and chack if it is correct for every $m$, it as to be for $\infty$. The thing is that I can't solve it. Any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that if $x>1$, then
$$
\frac{1}{x-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{-k}.
$$
Therefore it is sufficient to show that
$$
\frac{\sum^{n}_{j=1}x_j^{k+1}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}{x^{2k+1}_j}}\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\prod^n_{j=1}{x_j^k}}}.
$$
This is not hard now.